# React native - siganlR

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, signalr

I'm having trouble parsing data sent from signalR hub to my client variables.

So heres how it goes,

I activate my signalR listener on my client, and i extract the message like so:

```
connection.on('StreamData', message => {
                    // catch message here.
                    console.log("Message recieved ", message)
                });
```

and i get smth like this:

```
Message recieved  Object {
  "Alarms": Array [
    Object {
      "isActive": true,
      "name": "Alarm1",
    },
    Object {
      "isActive": true,
      "name": "Alarm2",
    },
    Object {
      "isActive": true,
      "name": "Alarm3",
    }]
},
  "Temperature1": 13,
  "Temperature2": 0,
  "Temperature3": 0
}
```

so the thing is i want to pass these parameters and set variables on the clients side, like

```
clientTemerature1 = message.Temperature1;
```